# Naming resulting data.table columns after aggregation in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I want to make aggregations in a data.table using functions that return can multiple rows, like `summary()` or `quantile()`. The way I do it so far is this:

```
library(data.table)
x = as.data.table(iris)
x[, as.list(c(summary(Sepal.Length), summary(Sepal.Width))), by = Species]
```

This works, but results in arbitrary column names. If I have a vector of length 12, `myColumnNames`, how can I set the new columns to be named after this vector (without using setnames in the next row)?

My "obvious" attempt, `x[, myColumnNames = as.list(c(summary(Sepal.Length), summary(Sepal.Width))), by = Species]` failed. Any ideas?

Comment: How about `x[, setNames(as.list(c(summary(Sepal.Length), summary(Sepal.Width))), myColumnNames), by = Species]`

Comment: What @akrun said or you can set the names after with `data.table::setnames`. For instance `setnames(y,2:13,myColumnNames)`, where `y` is the result of your line.

Comment: @akrun Your solution works perfectly, thanks! Please post it, so I can accept it as the correct asnwer.
@nicola I wanted to avoid `setnames()` after the command, in order to avoid playing with indices like `2:13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `setNames`

```
x[, setNames(as.list(c(summary(Sepal.Length), 
        summary(Sepal.Width))), myColumnNames), by = Species]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Are you implying there are more options as well?

Comment: @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos  The second option is `setnames` as @nicola commented